# I want an example of principal ideal domain that is not a Jacobson ring (PID but non-Jacobson ring)

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

Please give me an example principal ideal domain that is not a Jacobson ring. Its better this ring be commutative.

Comment: You have to look for a principial ideal domain with vanishing jacobson radical.

Comment: I meant non vanishing. Look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring

Comment: It hasn't example for my question. i saw it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply $\Bbb Z_{(2)}$ works: the localization of the integers at the complement of the prime ideal $2\Bbb Z$.

A localization of a PID is still a PID, and now the ring is local with a very large Jacobson radical, so zero is not an intersection of maximal ideals.